# using a try catch statement to keep a text box cleared

Tags: c#, forms, user-interface

I am making a windows form application that takes various game entries (title,genre,price) and then stores them in an array with a maximum of four entries.

The error I am having is that if there are no values entered in my text boxes, I want a message box to appear to force the user to enter values.  This happens.

The problem is that after this, it does not give the user another try. It just stops the program. I have tried using a try catch statement to do this but I am not quite sure how to use this. Would this be the correct solution?

```
namespace gameForm
{
 public partial class gameEntryForm : Form
{
    public gameEntryForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    struct Game
    {
        public string Title;
        public string Genre;
        public decimal Price;
    }

    static Game[] aNewGame = new Game[4]; //max size of the array is 4 

    static int newGameEntryIndex = 1;

    private void gameEntryForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        aNewGame[0].Title = "golf tour"; //this is a game already stored in the database
        aNewGame[0].Genre = "sports";
        aNewGame[0].Price = 1.99m;
    }

    private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(tbGenre.Text))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("please enter a Game genre.");
            }

            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(tbTitle.Text))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("please enter a Game title");
            }

            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(tbPrice.Text))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("please enter a Game price");
            }
        }



        //catch()
        //{


        //}


        aNewGame[newGameEntryIndex].Title = tbTitle.Text;

        aNewGame[newGameEntryIndex].Genre = tbGenre.Text;

        aNewGame[newGameEntryIndex].Price = Convert.ToDecimal(tbPrice.Text);

        newGameEntryIndex++;

        MessageBox.Show("entry saved");

        //clears the text boxes 
        tbTitle.Clear();

        tbGenre.Clear();

        tbPrice.Clear();
    }

    private void btnShow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        rtbShow.Text = "Game Details \n\nGame 1 \n" + aNewGame[0].Title + "\n" + aNewGame[0].Genre + "\n" + aNewGame[0].Price + "\n\n" + "Game 2 \n" + aNewGame[1].Title + "\n" + aNewGame[1].Genre + "\n" + aNewGame[1].Price + "\n\n" + "Game 3 \n" + aNewGame[2].Title + "\n" + aNewGame[2].Genre + "\n" + aNewGame[2].Price + "\n\n" + "Game 4 \n" + aNewGame[3].Title + "\n" + aNewGame[3].Genre + "\n" + aNewGame[3].Price; ;
    }
    //clears the rich text box
    private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        rtbShow.Clear();
    }

    private void btnQuit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You have not put the code that will throw an exception within the `try` block, and you do not catch it. `aNewGame[1]` doesn't exist so you can't set its properties.

Comment: `I have tried using a try catch statement to do this` side note: don't use `try/catch` statements to determine code flow...

Comment: I'd actually have the Save Button deactivated and use Validation to activate it only if the TextBoxes are populated correctly. See also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/user-input-validation-in-windows-forms , https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/display-error-icons-for-form-validation-with-wf-errorprovider

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code for `btnSave_Click` you are testing the value of the various `TextBox`es and displaying a message if they are `NULL` or empty.

However, you continue execution of your code *even if they are NULL or empty*.

You should stop processing more code if the conditions fail so that you don't try to use the `NULL`\empty values.

Something like:

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(tbGenre.Text))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("please enter a Game genre.");
    }
    else if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(tbTitle.Text))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("please enter a Game title");
    }
    else if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(tbPrice.Text))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("please enter a Game price");
    }
    else
    {
        // You forgot to create the new game at this index
        aNewGame[newGameEntryIndex] = new Game();

        aNewGame[newGameEntryIndex].Title = tbTitle.Text;
        aNewGame[newGameEntryIndex].Genre = tbGenre.Text;
        aNewGame[newGameEntryIndex].Price = Convert.ToDecimal(tbPrice.Text);

        newGameEntryIndex++;

        MessageBox.Show("entry saved");

        //clears the text boxes 
        tbTitle.Clear();
        tbGenre.Clear();
        tbPrice.Clear();
    }
}
```

I've also added a line:

```
aNewGame[newGameEntryIndex] = new Game();
```

As I couldn't see anywhere that you created the new `Game` object before trying to set it's properties.

Comment: `IsNullOrWhitespace` may be even better suited. You'd probably not want a Title of "    "?

Answer (score 2):

Add a return, no try/catch required:

```
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(tbGenre.Text))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("please enter a Game genre.");
                return; // Exit current function
            }
```

Try/catch is for when you have exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

`Try-Catch` is of no use to you.
What you should do is in the `btnSave_Click` method `return` when the textboxes are not populated:

```
if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tbGenre.Text) ||
    String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tbTitle.Text) ||
    String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tbPrice.Text)
{
  MessageBox.Show("Please enter a game genre, game title and game price.");
  return;
}

aNewGame[newGameEntryIndex].Title = tbTitle.Text;
...
```

There is another solution you could do. Only activate the `Save`-button if all three textboxes has values in them.

Something like:

```
private void ValidateGameData(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tbGenre.Text) ||
      String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tbTitle.Text) ||
      String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tbPrice.Text))
  {
    btnSave.Enabled = false;
  }
  else
  {
    btnSave.Enabled = true;
  }
}

tbGenre.TextChanged += ValidateGameData;
tbTitle.TextChanged += ValidateGameData;
tbPrice.TextChanged += ValidateGameData;
```

Comment: +1 For validation. Maybe it's a good idea to use the appropriate event(s): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.validating?view=netframework-4.8 <-- see example